# How do I setup a redirect/alias for the Ubuntu wiki?

Tags: community, ubuntu-wiki

I have a wiki page that I'd like to setup a redirect (or an alias).

I have http://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice, and I'd like to have http://wiki.ubuntu.com/libreoffice be a re-direct.

Also, is there a reason that the Ubuntu Wiki is so case-sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a redirect on the libreoffice page at the top:

```
#REDIRECT LibreOffice
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge! Knew it was simple, wasn't sure how simple. :)